# How do I store user input as a char*?

Tags: c++, string, char

In my main method,

```
int main()
{
        char *words = (char *)"GETGETYETYET";
        char *pattern = (char *)"GET";
        return 0;
}
```

Instead of *words and *pattern being a predefined char set, I want to get user input, the user types in the name of a .txt file, and I want the strings in that .txt file to be stored as (char *).
How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `std::string` and `std::fstream`.

Comment: Just a note, use `const char *` (or better, `std::string`) instead of `char *`. Modifying string literals is undefined behaviour, so there's nothing to gain from using `char *`.

Answer (score 2):

You **don't**.

Unless you want to deal with string allocations, deallocations, and ownerships, with buffer overruns and security problems, you just use `std::string`...

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string a = "abcde";
  std::string b;
  getline(std::cin, b);
  std::cout << a << ' ' << b;
  return 0;
}
```

Suppose your strings are on the file `x.txt`, one per line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::string line;
  std::ifstream f("x.txt");
  while( std::getline(f, line) )
    std::cout << ' ' << line << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The point here being that you really don't want to store things in `char*`...

Comment: Yeah, no it [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86746f166ae29901).

Comment: Listen, the problem is that you should use `std::getline` because `std::cin` does [not have a member called `getline`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abf5beadc99010d8). But even if you fix it, you are still missing the point of the question. What is it asking?

Comment: come on, yes, I read the question, and I quote:

> I want the strings in that .txt file to be stored as (char *). How can I do this?

The answer is still: you **don't** unless you want a world of hurt.

What the original question **really wants to do** is use `ifstream` for reading the .txt file and `string` for storing its contents, ...

Editing again:...

Comment: "I want the strings in that .txt file to be stored as (char *). How can I do this?" -- Except that that was never the question. The question, since the beginning, was all about letting the user choose and input file and retrieve the content in a string. Your answer just says "use `std::string`". How can it be an answer?

Comment: @Jefffrey - sounds like you should be submitting your own answer , and let the voters decide :)

Comment: No need to argue, my question was absurd, I understand how to use ifstream to read and store the text file as strings. I originally asked to store it in a (* char) because I have a method that takes in only chars, not strings....

Comment: @user3205160, `std::string` provides a `c_str` method to retrieve the underlying `char*` just for this purpose.

Comment: @Jefffrey, Technically, it does have a member function `getline`, but that takes a `char *` instead of a `std::string`. The free version is much better.